# Create backbone model ignoring defaults

Tags: backbone.js, model

I am new to backbone and I am wanting to create a model without default values added to it. It is necessary for updates done through the AJAX to update only changed fields (Defaults would reset values here).

Any ideas? Is there a native way of doing it?

Comment: Found out that clear() function after instantiation removes attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, which will give you a distinct subclass you can use when you want a no-default version verses when you want to make a new record that does use defaults.

```
var MyModelNoDefaults = MyModel.extend({defaults: {}});
```